# Перевести число из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную рекурсией

Tags: c++, рекурсия, системы-счисления

Всем привет,вот такой у меня вариант решения,но он не работает так как надо,может кто-то подсказать как исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int Recurs(int number){
    if(number > 1)
        Recurs(number/2);
    cout << number % 2;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Enter natural number"<< endl;
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    cout << Recurs(number);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас функции, которые должны возвращать `int`, не возвращают ничего. Также непонятно, зачем `cout << Recurs(number)`, вывод на экран у Вас и так есть.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int Recurs(int number){
    if(number > 1)
        Recurs(number/2);
    cout << number % 2;
    return 0;                               /* <-- */
}

int main(){
    cout << "Enter natural number"<< endl;
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    Recurs(number);                         /* <-- */
    return 0;                               /* <-- */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот теперь всё работает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int Recurs(int number){
    if(number > 1)
    Recurs(number /2);
    cout << number % 2;
    return number;
}
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL , "Ukrainian");
    cout << "Введите натуральное число" << endl;
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    Recurs(number);
}
```